# Reading from a NetworkStream fails after StreamReader did

Tags: c#, http, stream, network-programming, streamreader

I have a method that reads an HTTP request from a Stream (in fact it's a NetworkStream) in a very primitive way. First I read the header line by line and when I see the separator (aka empty line) I start reading the body.

The code looks like this:

```
public byte[] ReceiveHttp(Stream stream)
{
    var headerLines = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII, false, 8192, true))
    {
        var requestLine = reader.ReadLine();
        while (true)
        {
            var headerLine = reader.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerLine))
            {
                // all header lines read
                break;
            }
            headerLine = headerLine.Trim();
            headerLines.Add(headerLine);
        }
    }

    var contentLength = RetrieveContentLengthFromHeaderLines(headerLines);

    var bytes = new byte[contentLength];
    var readbytesCount = 0;

    while (readbytesCount < contentLength)
    {
        var chunkBytesCount = stream.Read(bytes, 0, contentLength);
        readbytesCount += chunkBytesCount;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Now my problem is, that the subsequent read of the body keeps hanging sometimes. I mean the call to `stream.Read` blocks until some kind of timeout is reached.

When replacing all `StreamReader.ReadLine()` (in fact removing `StreamReader` from the code) with some custom code, that reads a line byte by byte until the line break occurs, the problem never occurs.

So, I guess there is some kind of buffering/caching inside `StreamReader` that may already have read the whole message but hides it from subsequent stream actions. But that's only a guess.

Does somebody have an idea, what causes this behavior and how I could get around it without using a custom byte-by-byte ReadLine method?

Comment: Yes you are right. `StreamReader` is reading ahead (there is even a buffer size: 8192). You could try to reduce it to 1 and see what happens, but I don't give any guarantee. The `ReadLine()` has some code to search ahead for the end of the line (because it can be composed of 1 or 2 characters, `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`), so I don't think it is really possible... if the file has all the lines terminated with `\n` or `\r\n` it could even work...

Comment: `StreamReader` uses a minimum of 128 bytes even if setting less.

Comment: The HTTP stream uses TCP as the transport layer.  TCP is broken up to a maximum of ~1500 bytes.  After the TCP is received the message is parsed in the HTTP Application layer which doesn't happen instantaneously and the TCP doesn't always run consistently.  virus checkers and firewalls may also be checking the TCP for contents which delay messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have already commented that it is quite complex (read impossible) to use `StreamReader` to read the headers of the http protocol. You have to read the `Stream` directly and split "by hand".

My line splitter:

```
// If you want to use UTF8:
// var encoding = (Encoding)Encoding.UTF8.Clone();
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"); 
var decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();

//Encoding.ASCII
var headerLines = new List<string>();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
char[] chars = new char[2];

while (true)
{
    int curr = stream.ReadByte();
    char ch = '\0';

    bool newLine = false;

    if (curr == -1)
    {
        newLine = true;
    }
    else
    {
        bytes[0] = (byte)curr;

        // There is the possibility of a partial invalid 
        // character (first byte of UTF8) plus a new valid 
        // character. In this case decoder.GetChars will
        // return 2 chars
        int count = decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, 1, chars, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ch = chars[i];

            if (ch == '\n')
            {
                newLine = true;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(ch);
            }
        }
    }

    if (newLine)
    {
        string str = sb.ToString();

        // Handling of \r\n
        if (ch == '\n' && str[str.Length - 1] == '\r')
        {
            str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
        }

        str = str.Trim();

        if (str.Length != 0)
        {
            headerLines.Add(str);
            sb.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (curr == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that for headers the suggested encoding is ISO-8859-1. The line ending can be both `\r\n` and `\n`. The code is quite complex because I wanted to handle UTF8. For other encodings it should be useless. Note that I `Trim()` **before** doing the check for length, so a line full only of spaces will still stop the reading of headers.